# Controlling Compute Engine Instance Name

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

When creating a managed instance group to manage GCP Compute Engine instances, we are required to set a "base_instance_name" to which Terraform will append a four character random string to ensure the instance name is unique.  See: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance_group_manager.html

Is there any way to control the instance names that are created when using a managed instance group such that the names are deterministic?  The other option is can we control where in the name the four character random string is placed?  In other words, can we have the string placed at the beginning of the hostname as opposed to the end?  The reason I ask is that I believe this is going to cause a problem if we install wildcard SSL certificates on these instances since the wildcard must be at the beginning of the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Not because of Terraform, but because it have been designed so by Google in [instanceGroupManagers REST object](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroupManagers). The documentation of `baseInstanceName` field (the one you can set via Terraform using `base_instance_name`) states that :

> The value must be 1-58 characters long. **Instances are named by appending a hyphen and a random four-character string to the base instance name**. The base instance name must comply with [RFC1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt).

This behavior cannot be changed.

For your SSL certificate install issues, I think you might need to put a load balancer in front of your instance group, and configure SSL on the load balancer rather than in the instances themselves. The [SSL Certificates section in the Load balancing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates) can be helpful.